Why my service worker in Angular isn't working or registering in browser?
I'm using Angular 16 with Node 18.20, so I use the command ng add @angular/pwa
Then I add a new command to run teh dist folder: "start-pwa": "ng build --configuration production --base-href=/ && http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/inno-app-16"
And run it like this: npm run start-pwa
Now in the page, in Application > Service Workers it not showing anything.!

And in manifest this is what is showing:

And it doesn't matter if I create a new app or use an old one, no one show teh service worker..!
This is my manifest:
{
  "name": "inno-app-16",
  "short_name": "inno-app-16",
  "theme_color": "#1976d2",
  "background_color": "#fafafa",
  "display": "standalone",
  "scope": "./",
  "start_url": "./",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-72x72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-96x96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-128x128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-144x144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-152x152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-192x192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-384x384.png",
      "sizes": "384x384",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    },
    {
      "src": "assets/icons/icon-512x512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "type": "image/png",
      "purpose": "maskable any"
    }
  ]
}

and my ngsw-config
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/service-worker/config/schema.json",
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "/manifest.webmanifest",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**",
          "/*.(svg|cur|jpg|jpeg|png|apng|webp|avif|gif|otf|ttf|woff|woff2)"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}

And I found a 'solution' in other question and it was to configure my service worker like this:
    ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
      enabled: !isDevMode(),
      registrationStrategy: 'registerImmediately'
    })

But if you have a 3th party libraries setInterval won't work, and also this solution didn't work for me.
